# как в pandas на основе DatetimeIndex одного массива получить значения из другого массива ориентируясь по его DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Есть дневные данные из файла `D`, на основе которых создается серия, и квартальные данные `Q` по которым так же создается серия в pandas.
Мне нужно, используя DatetimeIndex дневных данных, получить значения массива из квартальных данных. То есть, найти ближайшее значение, при этом DatetimeIndex квартального должен быть меньше или равен дневному (не должно быть "заглядывания вперёд").
Пример:

```
2018-06-30,    1207.4 #квартальное значение
    
2018-07-02 00:00:00, 1.58479 # ближайшее дневное
    
2018-07-02 00:00:00, 1207.4 #синхронизировали по времени значение из квартальных данных с дневным
```

Сейчас я использую основной цикл по D и вложенный в него цикл по Q.
Хотелось бы обойтись без циклов. Или быть может каким-либо образом numpy использовать, но у меня массивы разной длины.
Возможно, в pandas есть функция наподобие этой:

```
index = data1.index.get_loc('1991-10-15', "nearest")
```

но для массива.

P.S. Нужно именно быстрое получение данных. С помощью циклов понятно, как сделать.
Если есть ответ, как данную манипуляцию произвести в postgresql, то интересно было бы увидеть. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1299567/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-postgresql-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-timestam) задавал вопрос по этой теме.

Для лучшего понимания дополнил код функцией "def file", в которой циклы делают синхронизацию значений из квартальных данных с дневными. Если ее запустить, то наглядно видно, что мне необходимо. Данные бывают с различной частотой 7, 10 дней, месяц, квартал(не в одинаковые числа месяца).

Файлы закачал здесь: [D](https://dropmefiles.net/ru/9LA2) , [Q](https://dropmefiles.net/ru/my9Z4cUED)

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
        
    df = pd.read_csv('D.csv',
                         index_col='DATE',
                         parse_dates=True,
                         infer_datetime_format=True)
        
    date = df.iloc[:, 0].index.date
    z = df.iloc[:, 3].values
        
    df1 = pd.read_csv('Q.csv',
                         index_col='DATE',
                         parse_dates=True,
                         infer_datetime_format=True)
        
    date1 = df1.iloc[:, 0].index.date
    z1 = df1.iloc[:, 0].values
        
    date_ = np.array(date, dtype=np.datetime64)
    data = pd.Series(z, index=date_)
        
    date_1 = np.array(date1, dtype=np.datetime64)
    data1 = pd.Series(z1, index=date_1)
    
    def file(v,n,dv,dn): #v = z, n = z1, dv = date, dn = date1
        z = np.copy(v)
        news = np.copy(n)
        date = dv
        date_n = dn
        N = len(date)
        N1 = len(date_n)
        x = N1 - 1
        global u
        u = 0
    
        for q in range(0, N):
            k = u
            for i in range(k, N1):
                if date_n[i - 1] <= date[q] and date_n[i] > date[q]:
                    u = i
                    z[q] = news[i - 1]
                    break
                if x == i and date[q] >= date_n[i]:
                    u = i
                    z[q] = news[i]
                    break
    
        return z
    
    zn = file(z,z1,date,date1)
    test_data = pd.Series(zn, index=date_)
    print(test_data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятен вопрос. Пока я понял так - нужно найти в дневных данных значение, ближайшее по дате к имеющимся квартальным данным и дописать его в фрейм с квартальными данными. Если так, то это просто делается через ресамплинг и объединение:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('D.csv',
                     index_col='DATE',
                     parse_dates=True,
                     usecols=[0, 4],
                     infer_datetime_format=True)

df1 = pd.read_csv('Q.csv',
                     index_col='DATE',
                     parse_dates=True,
                     infer_datetime_format=True)

df = df.resample("Q").last()
res = df1.join(df, how="inner")
```

получите res:

```
                 O        C
DATE                       
1991-03-31   493.8  108.400
1991-06-30   485.6  105.530
1991-09-30   492.5  106.300
1991-12-31   500.3   94.900
1992-03-31   504.4  102.060
...            ...      ...
2017-06-30  1179.0   86.355
2017-12-31  1191.5   87.939
2018-06-30  1207.4   81.947
2018-12-31  1225.3   77.250
2019-06-30  1237.9   75.763

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

в котором в колонке "C" будут ближайшие дневные данные к имеющимся квартальным.

Если нужно наоборот, в дневной датафрейм добавить  данные квартального, то можно сделать так:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('D.csv',
                     index_col='DATE',
                     parse_dates=True,
                     usecols=[0, 4],
                     infer_datetime_format=True)

df1 = pd.read_csv('Q.csv',
                     index_col='DATE',
                     parse_dates=True,
                     infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Нужно обратить внимание на разные временные промежутки в индексах обоих фреймов. в данном конкретном случае, если я не ошибаюсь, корректно будет расширить индекс квартального фрейма, для полного охвата индекса дневного фрейма:

```
df1 = df1.reindex(pd.date_range(df1.index.max(), df.index.max()).union(df1.index), method="pad")
```

Ну и затем:

```
df1 = df1.resample("D").fillna(method="ffill")
df["Q"] = df1.loc[df1.index.intersection(df.index)]
df["Q"] = df["Q"].fillna(method="ffill")
```

тогда df будет:

```
                  C       Q
DATE                       
1991-02-04  102.230   489.0
1991-02-05  100.620   489.0
1991-02-06  100.010   489.0
1991-02-07  100.470   489.0
1991-02-08   99.650   489.0
...             ...     ...
2021-07-01   83.281  1237.9
2021-07-02   83.534  1237.9
2021-07-05   83.472  1237.9
2021-07-06   82.876  1237.9
2021-07-07   82.755  1237.9

[7849 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Нужно наоборот значения из квартальных данных перенести на дневное время. Дополнил в основном сообщении код, с вызовом функции, которая делает, то что нужно через циклы.

Comment: я обновил ответ.

Comment: Проверил циклом Ваши и свои данные. Совпадают, кроме последнего значения. Вот здесь должно было произойти обновление: 2019-07-01 00:00:00 1225.3 2019-07-01 00:00:00 1237.9     . Слева Ваши данные, справа посчитанные функцией.

Comment: я обновил ответ. проблема в том, что индекс датафрейма. из которого берем ремамлинг, должен охватывать индекс целевого датафрейма. поэтому я его расширил. в идеале вы можете сделать автоматическую проверку и расширить индекс от минимальной даты из двух фреймов до максимальной даты из двух фреймов.